# Effectiveness of Layered EM wave shields

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radio

Which is best at shielding EM waves;  a Faraday cage with sides made of blocks of metal, or layers of metal (with insulation ie plastic & without), or is there no difference between the three? & why? Can any difference be calculated?

To give a hypothetical example to illustrate my question: I'd presume the frequency was 100Hz, & the material aluminum, the layers are 1mm thick up to the required amount therefore individually less than the skin depth (approx. 8.2mm). The insulating separators are also 1mm thick.

('Best' meaning EM shielding achieved using least thickness of metal)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by blocks. I think a mesh with spacing less than the wavelength would use the least metal.

Comment: Could you precise the range of the wavelengths of the EM waves?

Comment: The "best" scientific solution for a technical problem is an "engineering" question and it always has to be asked with an appropriate goal function. Are you looking for the cheapest, the lightest, the most durable, the most temperature resistant or the best looking solution? How wide a frequency range does it have to cover? Can it be reflective or does it have to be absorptive? These are just a few of the possible dimensions that such a problem has...

Comment: @ Keith McClary & no_ choice99 & CuriousOne :
I was looking for an answer along the lines of David's response below, although probably needed to give more detail to be clearer. Please see addition to question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the vast majority of practical circumstances, there would be no difference between the blocks of metal and layers of metal. The reason is that only the surface of the metal (more precisely, a thin layer with a thickness on the order of a few microns for milimeterwaves/microwaves e.g Wifi frequencies) interacts with the EM wave. If the metal is roughly as thin or thinner than a quantity called the skin depth of the metal, then the EM wave can penetrate the metal, and multiple layers might be relevant. This usually isn't relevant though, unless you're dealing with extremely low frequency waves, or extremely thin materials.

Comment: @ David: Correction: Thanks, so whether the cage was made of blocks or layers of metal would be irrelevant at any frequency (both exactly the same), only if the quantity of metal utilised in each shield was of the same thickness

Comment: That's correct. If you're using multiple layers, you might as well use a single layer with the same total thickness.